# MarkLogic Server Side Javascript invoke from Java

Tags: marklogic

I am new to MarkLogic. Is that possible to call the server side javascript module from the java.
Below is the code.

```
        ServerEvaluationCall invoker = client
                .newServerEval()
                .modulePath("/test/Test.sjs");
          invoker.eval();
          EvalResultIterator result = invoker.eval();
```

i tried but it gives me error like "com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: failed to apply resource at invoke: Internal Server Error."

Comment: Have you tried invoking the SJS main module in QueryConsole to make sure it executes?  Did you install the SJS main module via the Java or REST API so it is executable by a REST API user with all of the invoke privileges (see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_47331 )? Using the Admin UI, you can look at the server log. If that doesn't have more information, you can use the Group dialog in the Admin UI to change the file logging level to debug, which should provide more detail about why the module is not invoked.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding,
I am able to execute and call my dependent modules from my main module via query console. Placed my dependent modules manually on the server<Server/Modules/myApp/***.sjs>.
I dont know how to inject/install these dependent modules to marklogic server using Java, as well as how to refer them in the main modules. Appreciate if you share any details about this implementation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say, "Placed my dependent modules manually on the server", that sounds like you didn't use the Java or REST API to install the modules. As noted above, that's important because it assigns the correct execute privileges to the modules.

Comment: I am using ResourceExtensionsManager and written the SJS as module in MarkLogic Server. By extending ResourceManager, can able to access the module. As mentioned in the reference  (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices). Its working.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you've switched from the module invocation approach to the resource service extension approach, which solved the problem for you.  If you ever do need the module invocation approach, the guidelines are here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_70532